# Existe alguna forma de comprobar un error en ejecucion en c++?

Tags: c++

El 47 es la posicion desde donde termina el ultimo numero, el 244, desde este agarra hasta el ultimo `' '`, quiero convertir a numeros solo aquellos strings que lo sea con el stod, pero si agarro un espacio vacio me salta un error, existe una forma de controlar ese error para en caso de que agarre un string y lo intente convertir a numero, se haga otra cosa?

```
            string prueba = "255 254 255 255 252 255 255 249 251 255 244 244    "; //46

            cout<<prueba.substr(prueba.find(' ')+1)<<endl;
            cout<<(prueba.substr(47, prueba.find(' ')));
            if(stod(prueba.substr(47, prueba.find(' ')))=="error"){
             "nueva accion para no caer en error"
            }
```

Comment: Si estás procesando enteros, en vez de `stod` deberías usar [`stoi`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/stoi)

Answer (score 2):

Amigo, bienvenido al mundo de las excepciones. Mira, cuando tengas problemas
con como utilizar una función, siempre te recomiendo que visites
cppreference.com. Si vamos a la pagina de documentacion de
[stod](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stof), veras que
si falla porque lo que le estas pasando no es un numero, va a lanzar (`throw`
en c++) un `std::invalid_argument`. Entonces lo que tienes que hacer es atrapar
esa excepción (`catch` en c++).

Entonces tienes que poner ese codigo que puede fallar en un bloque `try catch`:

```cpp
try {

    // Aqui encajas tu stod(prueba.substr(47, prueba.find(' '))

} catch (const std::invalid_argument& e) {

    std::cout << "No se pudo realizar la convercion\n" << e.what() << '\n';

}
```